# Why IGNORECASE awk variable does not work properly when its value is set in the command line option?

Tags: linux, awk

I realized that `awk -v IGNORECASE=0` is ignoring the case when it shouldn't.

```
ps -ef | awk -v IGNORECASE=0 '/INIT/'
root          1      0  0  2019 ?        00:03:07 /sbin/init
root      65327  25751  0 08:26 pts/0    00:00:00 awk -v IGNORECASE=0 /INIT/
```

but `awk 'BEGIN { IGNORECASE=0 }'` is not ignoring the case as expected.

```
ps -ef | awk  'BEGIN { IGNORECASE=0 } /INIT/'
root      66290  25751  0 08:27 pts/0    00:00:00 awk BEGIN { IGNORECASE=0 } /INIT/
```

Why? What am I missing? Is it a bug?

P.D: GNU Awk 3.1.7

Comment: Please, before adding your answer, read carefully my question.

Comment: I have GNU Awk 5.0.1 and it is working as expected, both with the command-line option and in the begin block. Hence the bug theory seems plausible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found in the gawk changelog:

> 2015-02-05         Andrew J. Schorr
>
> - eval.c (set_IGNORECASE): If IGNORECASE has a numeric value, try
>     using that before treating it as a string.  This fixes a problem
>     where setting -v IGNORECASE=0 on the command line was not working
>     properly.

Bug confirmed. You're not missing anything.

Hopefully you can upgrade to the latest version.

Comment: Hi, @RavinderSingh13, it wasn't a link, I found it in the file `ChangeLog.1` in the top-level directory of the gawk source code. I'm not sure if it's also accessible on line somewhere. In any case, you can get the source here: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Accessing-The-Source.html